# System.UnauthorizedAccessException while accessing network shared file through IIS7.5 application on windows server 2008

Tags: networking, iis-7

I found similar looking issues, however none of the solution i found have worked for me. I do not have much knowledge about IIS or network security so posting my issue here. If anyone has any comments, i would really appreciate.

I am running my webApplication under IIS7.5 on windows server 2008.

-Web Server Machine is not domain controlled.

-Through web application, I am trying to access a network Shared location (machine1 which is also not domain controlled).

- I keep on getting this error "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "\\Machine1\Shared\Test.txt" is denied." I am using UNC Path.
- I shared the network shared directory with Full permissions to various users including, "everyone", "Network service", "IUSR", "IIS_IUSRS". Just to see it working firstly.
- web application is running under IIS in their own application pool with "Managed pipeline mode" as classic and "Identity" as "Network Service".
  Note: even tried changing mode to "integrated". It did not work.
- I want to run IIS under Network Service. Running IIS under any other user account matching with an user account on network shared is not a solution for me either. 
  Even though i tried it, could not make it working.
- I used process monitor on the network computer which has shared directory and i was expecting network service to access the file, however i do not see any process trying to access the file or create it. I am not sure either Which process is expected to access this file and under which account?

Looking for help.